# User control with extended properties

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, typeconverter

I am developing a user control and I need it to have a custom extended property

```
public class mycontrol: UserControl
{
    public mycontrol()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    ExtendedProperty property= new ExtendedProperty();
    [Browsable(true)]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
    [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public ExtendedProperty Thing
    {
        get
        {
            return property;
        }
        set
        {
            property.Text = value.Lbl1Text;
            property.Duration=value.duration;
            property= value;
            this.control1.Text=value.Text;
            this.control2.duration=value.duration;
            this.Refresh();
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
}

[RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint)]
[Category("Line")]
[Browsable(true)]
public class ExtendedProperty
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler propertChanged;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "";
    }

    string text= "tt";

    [Category("Line")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint)]
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return text;
        }
        set
        {
            text= value;
            propertChanged("text");
        }
    }

    int duration= 5;

    [Category("Line")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint)]
    public string Duration
    {
        get
        {
            return duration;
        }
        set
        {
            duration= value;
            propertChanged("duration");
        }
    }

    void propertChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if(propertChanged!=null)
        propertChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

In the property grid I can see 'Thing' and 'sub properties (Text, Duration)' but when I edit them the changes are not reflected on the GUI (control1.Text and control2.Duration are not changing).

Comment: Could it be as simple as a case inside `propertyChanged`? You have property `Text`, but you rise event for `text`, you see? Disregards of outcome, please follow  [naming guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx). Class name `mycontrol` makes my heart bleeding.

Comment: I had the solution, I had to handle the event propertChanged in MyControl UserControl
I coded this sample in this website editor and this code is a dummy code 
anyway thank you for your useful answer Mr.Camel Case

Comment: You post broken code, you get broken answer. As expected ;)

Comment: You enjoy that. Don't you? :D

Comment: You can edit own question to do corrections or add missing information. It is advisable to either copy-paste **exact** related code or prepare [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first. *Coding in this website editor* is not advisable, because if you make obvious mistakes people will answer you to correct those and not your original problem. Currently code contains mistake which my first comment possible answer (notice, I didn't post it as an answer, because I was expecting bad "copy/paste" case).